# PHP in subdirectories doesn't execute

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I'm running a LAMP server locally, and PHP in the root (/var/www/) folder seems to work fine. However, when I try to navigate to PHP files in /var/www/foo/ they just download instead of being executed.

Any idea what's up here?

Comment: Remove .htaccess file and try again

Comment: I don't have one. At least I didn't make one and there isn't one in /var/www. Would it be somewhere else?

Comment: check your httpd.config/ apache config file is you properly mapped there or not

Comment: The httpd.conf file is empty. What should be in it?